# SQL Server - Convert String to float with N/A's present

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a flat file that I loaded into SQL Server using the import wizard.  All columns are stored as nchar(50).

I'm now trying to convert the table to a new table with various types (char, float, int, etc).

There is one column that I'd like to convert to float but it contains N/A strings.

I checked that there weren't any other weird string using this:

```
SELECT col1, count(*)
from tab1
where ISNUMERIC(col1) <> 1
group by col1
```

Then I wrote a CASE statement to do the conversion:

```
SELECT CASE WHEN col1 = 'N/A' THEN NULL ELSE CAST(col1 AS FLOAT) END col1
INTO tab2
FROM tab1
```

But I'm getting this error message:

```
Msg 8114, Level 16, State 5, Line 1
Error converting data type nvarchar to float.
```

Any idea what's causing this?

Comment: Careful on using `ISNUMERIC()` for this. What do you get when you run `select * from table where column like '%[^0-9\.]%' escape '\'`

Answer (score 5):

If 2012+ Use try_convert()

```
SELECT col1, count(*)
from tab1
where try_convert(float,col1) is null
group by col1
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use try_convert if you want to ignore invalid chars to float as below

```
Select try_convert(float, col1) as col1 from yourtable
```

Answer (score 2):

Careful on using `ISNUMERIC()` for this. It can return some false positives. For example...

```
select isnumeric('$')
select isnumeric('1e4')
```

This should show you what is causing the error.

```
select * from table where column like '%[^0-9\.]%' escape '\'
```

You can use this in a where clause, or use `TRY_CONVERT()`

Comment: Plus 1 for demonstrating the potential false positives

Comment: Another fun one is "D" double  --- select isnumeric('123d4')

Comment: @scsimon : good point it was breaking on comma's in the strings

Comment: No worries @screechOwl, and that is a language formatting which as you see would have been accepted. Glad you got it all worked out.

Answer (score 1):

You aren't doing the type conversion from the String to the float. In your SQL statements you need to explicitly cast the original column type from nvarchar to float. Something like this might work:

```
SELECT
    CASE
        WHEN col1 = 'N/A' THEN NULL
        ELSE CAST(col1 AS FLOAT) 
    END col1
INTO tab2
FROM tab1
```